# Select All across Paging and Display Results per page, whilst Disabling and Enabling a Button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Select All option, with a button. On load the button is disabled. if you choose the select all or two or more select items in the list the button is disabled. However, I have paging and a display for a number of items to show in the table. Is there a way I can persist it so that it works across paging, and when the display number is changed?

**Here is my code:**

```
//Disable Top Verify Button if two or more checkboxes are selected.
    $(document)('.verifyshipment-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $(document).on(".individual").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('.verifyshipment-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.verifyshipment-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    //Select All
    $('.verifyshipment-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $(document).on(".selectall").click(function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('.verifyshipment-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.verifyshipment-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

**Paging and Display options**

```
$(document).on("click",
        "#indexPager a",
        function() {
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('disabled') || $(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
                return false;
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                    addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    $(document).on("change",
        "#pageSizeSelector",
        function() {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: selectedValue,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                    addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You would have to save the "logic" that knows if they should be disabled or not,  in some sort of session or cookie,

Comment: You can add the rowNumber and pageNumber as an object in the local/session storage, every time you change page you can check if there was something checked or not!

Comment: okay, I think a session, could be good. the application is written in C# so I think some backend, would be better than relying on the dom to achieve this, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous commenters have pointed out, you really have two options:

(1) Saving the data on your application server (via something like a session cookie) and then making your client query the server for that information when it needs it.

(2) Saving the data in the [session/local storage of your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and retrieving it from there when you need it.

If you need this option to persist across devices (i.e., user switches computers in the middle of the interaction flow you have presented), then the best way to do it would be (1). However, adding additional data to the backend can be a pain if you are not a backend developer (e.g., do you know how / have permission to create / manipulate databases and create new api endpoints?).

For everything else, I would recommend using (2), specifically session storage which will automatically garbage collect the data when the user session is over (survives reloads but gets deleted when browser is closed). If you need more manual data management you can use the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser.